# How to prove that the sequence $X_{n+1} = 1/2 × (X_n+\sin(X_n)\cos(X_n)) >0 $

Tags: sequences-and-series

In a exercise i need to prove that the sequence :

$$X_{n+1} = \frac12(X_n+\sin(X_n)\cos(X_n))$$
converges to do that i need to prove that the sequence is decreasing by using $\sin(X_n)\cos(X_n)=\sin(2X_n)/2$ and than i have to prove that $X_n > 0$ by induction.

Comment: To make questions easy to read,  it is recommended the use of [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write mathematical equations and/or expressions. Also, adding some context in the way of things you tried but failed, where you get stuck, or ask for hints will improve your question. Some people are too sensitive to this kind of things and are quick to pull the trigger on downvotes without giving any positive feedback to questioners.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\frac{1}{2}(x+\sin x\,\cos x)=\frac{1}{4}(2x+\sin(2x))=\frac{x}{2}\big(1+\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}\big)$

If $t>0$, what can you say about $\frac{\sin t}{t}$?

Comment: I am sorry but i didn't get it, can you pleas help me i want to prove that Xn > 0

Comment: Try to do some analysis on the function $t\mapsto \frac{\sin t}{t}=\operatorname{sinc}(t)$. It is known that $|\operatorname{sinc}(t)|\leq 1$. Use some differential calculus to see that.

Comment: A plot say between 0 to 20 should give you an idea. Notices that as $t\rightarrow0$, $\operatorname{sinc}(t)\rightarrow1$, which is something you may already know.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't heard about sinc function before